# What is the checksum algorithm in SQLite WAL

Tags: sqlite, checksum, wal

I'm wondering about the checksum algorithm in SQLite WAL mode 
I already checked doc file but it says like this (this image is captured in sqlite doc file https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#section_4_1)

[image: Checksum algorithm in WAL mode SQLite]

I didn't understand what is the meaning of " The checksum values in the final 8 bytes of the frame-header exactly match the checksum computed consecutively on the first 24 bytes of the WAL header and the first 8 bytes and the content of all frames up to and including the current frame "

I want to understand more clearly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [next section of the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html) says:

> **Checksum Algorithm**
>
> The checksum is computed by interpreting the input as an even number of unsigned 32-bit integers: `x(0)` through `x(N)`. The 32-bit integers are big-endian if the magic number in the first 4 bytes of the WAL header is `0x377f0683` and the integers are little-endian if the magic number is `0x377f0682`. The checksum values are always stored in the frame header in a big-endian format regardless of which byte order is used to compute the checksum.
>
> The checksum algorithm only works for content which is a multiple of 8 bytes in length. In other words, if the inputs are `x(0)` through `x(N)` then N must be odd. The checksum algorithm is as follows:
>
> ```
> s0 = s1 = 0
> for i from 0 to n-1 step 2:
>    s0 += x(i) + s1;
>    s1 += x(i+1) + s0;
> endfor
> # result in s0 and s1
> ```
>
> The outputs `s0` and `s1` are both weighted checksums using Fibonacci weights in reverse order. (The largest Fibonacci weight occurs on the first element of the sequence being summed.) The `s1` value spans all 32-bit integer terms of the sequence whereas `s0` omits the final term.

Comment: Thanks but I want to know how to compare the checksum among
final 8 Byte of WAL Frame header , 24Byte WAL header, first 8 Bytes and contents of all frames.
I want to exactly know what is the first 8 Byte..means? is it means frame contents's 8Bytes?

Comment: @JongHyeokPark most welcome and you can mark it as correct if got the answer.